# Adding data based on date from another dataframe

Tags: r, linux, date, time, as.date

I have two datasets. One with multiple dates:

```
date, time
1   2013-05-01 12:43:34
2   2013-05-02 05:04:23
3   2013-05-02 09:34:34
4   2013-05-02 12:32:23
5   2013-05-03 23:23:23
6   2013-05-04 15:34:17
```

and one with sunrise and sunsets data:

```
Sunrise                Sunset 
2013-05-01 06:43:00    2013-05-01  21:02:12
2013-05-02 06:44:00    2013-05-02  21:03:13
2013-05-03 06:44:56    2013-05-03  21:04:02
2013-05-04 06:45:32    2013-05-04  21:05:00
```

I want to add a column to the first dataframe with either "Day" or "night", based on whether the date and time from the first dataframe is between the sunrise and sunset time and dates.

```
date, time                 Day or night
1   2013-05-01 12:43:34    Day
2   2013-05-02 05:04:23    Night
3   2013-05-02 09:34:34    Day
4   2013-05-02 12:32:23    Day
5   2013-05-03 23:23:23    Night
6   2013-05-04 15:34:17    Day
```

I tried copying and if_else functions, but the length of rows is different because for one year I have 365 sunrises and sunsets but I've also got multiple measurements for one day (total of 28000 rows).

Can anyone help me with my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You’re more likely to get a positive response if your question is reproducible. [See Stack Overflow question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 <- structure(list(date_time = c("2013-05-01 12:43:34", "2013-05-02 05:04:23", 
"2013-05-02 09:34:34", "2013-05-02 12:32:23", "2013-05-03 23:23:23", 
"2013-05-04 15:34:17")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(Sunrise = c("2013-05-01 06:43:00", "2013-05-02 06:44:00", 
"2013-05-03 06:44:56", "2013-05-04 06:45:32"), Sunset = c("2013-05-01 21:02:12", 
"2013-05-02 21:03:13", "2013-05-03 21:04:02", "2013-05-04 21:05:00"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.frame"))

# prepare df1
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(date_time = as.POSIXct(date_time, tz = "UTC")) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(date_time))

# prepare df2
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Sunrise = as.POSIXct(Sunrise, tz = "UTC")) %>%
  mutate(Sunset = as.POSIXct(Sunset, tz = "UTC")) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Sunrise))

library(lubridate) # for the use of interval

merge(df1, df2, by = "Date") %>%
  mutate(DayOrNight = ifelse(date_time %within% interval(Sunrise, Sunset), "Day", "Night"))

#         Date           date_time             Sunrise              Sunset DayOrNight
# 1 2013-05-01 2013-05-01 12:43:34 2013-05-01 06:43:00 2013-05-01 21:02:12        Day
# 2 2013-05-02 2013-05-02 05:04:23 2013-05-02 06:44:00 2013-05-02 21:03:13      Night
# 3 2013-05-02 2013-05-02 09:34:34 2013-05-02 06:44:00 2013-05-02 21:03:13        Day
# 4 2013-05-02 2013-05-02 12:32:23 2013-05-02 06:44:00 2013-05-02 21:03:13        Day
# 5 2013-05-03 2013-05-03 23:23:23 2013-05-03 06:44:56 2013-05-03 21:04:02      Night
# 6 2013-05-04 2013-05-04 15:34:17 2013-05-04 06:45:32 2013-05-04 21:05:00        Day
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed!